# A number theory problem I saw, related to prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Prove that there are infinitely many prime factors of numbers of the form $2^{3^k}+1$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Besides @BrunoB's nice feedback, what is the point of the curly braces?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I think they're asking whether the set $\left\{2^{3^k} + 1 \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ contains infinitely many prime numbers.

Comment: Based on the notion of *prime factors*, my primary thought was that *the union set of the prime factors of $\{2^{3^k}+1\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is infinite.*

Comment: Nevertheless, this sequence cannot contain infinitely many primes, as $3|2^{3^{k}}+1$.

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

For $N=3^k$, consider $2^{3N}+1=(2^N+1)(2^{2N}-2^N+1)$.

Let $C$ be a common factor of $2^N+1$ and $2^{2N}-2^N+1$.

Then, modulo $C$, $2^N\equiv -1$ and $2^{2N}-2^N+1\equiv 3$.

Therefore $2^N+1$ and $2^{2N}-2^N+1$ have gcd $3$.

Can you now see how to complete the proof?

Comment: I wish people would say why they downvote!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people downvoted because you've answered a PSQ

Comment: What does PSQ mean?

Comment: A problem statement question. For more details on why you shouldn't answer them, see [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: @DS I gave a hint not an answer and because it was downvoted I gave further details.

Comment: Still, you're helping a person who thinks they can just post their questions and get a solution easily, without showing their work, as if we are a _Do My Homework Forum_.

Comment: @DS Many thanks for your clarification. I am not convinced that giving a hint is in the same category as giving 'an hastily written answer' but I can see the issue here.

Comment: I guess a hint is enough. This issue is a part of a number theory problem related to LTE.